# correlation coefficients or feature importances from classification or regression algorithm model

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, regression

I have created my sample data for machine learning just to checkout how classification and regression models work.

My sample data has 50 rows with columns for `Memory`, `CPU`, `Responsetime`. I have generated `Responsetime` using a formula `Memory*2 + CPU*0.7`.

Now when I use this data to generate models for classification using different algorithms like *DecisionTree*, *RandomForest*, *SVM*, *NaiveBayes*, *SGD*, *LogisticRegression*, I get back kappa and correlation coefficients (`model.coef_`) from the model and feature importances in case of decision tree, random forest.

The coefficient values returned for `Memory` and `CPU` are no where near to my formula that I used to generate these values of response time. I am not able to understand whether my models generated are right to use for prediction in this case or not.

For regression, *Linear Regression* did give me right coefficients matching with my formula.

Comment: `model.coef_` do not give the correlation coefficients. They give the final weights of the features. Also, this is simply a regression problem, not classification (you are not classifying the data into 2 or more fixed classes).

Comment: My bad for incomplete explanation on classification model generation. I converted Response time column to a new true/False column by adding a condition like if ResponseTime > 200, true otherwise false. And deleted original ResponseTime column. So now I have "Memory", "CPU" and "True/False" column and I am running classification algorithms on it. The coefficients generated for Memory and CPU are turning out to be 1 and 0 with DecisionTree for example with kappa=1. For Random Forest, Memory is 0.2 and CPU is 0.7 with Kappa=1

Answer (score 1):

You gave a linear formula: `(Memory*2 + CPU*0.7)` and linear regression, a method that learns the `B_j` values in `y_i = B_0*1 + B_1*X_i_1 + ... + B_n*X_i_n`, was able to model that with the coefficients you would expect. That's because the form of the linear regression model matches the form of your equation, so it makes sense to match the coefficients directly.

For your classification algorithms, not only does the form of the equation not match your linear equation, but the problem is also not really a classification problem. You have given an example that is distinctly a regression problem.

Comment: My bad for incomplete explanation on classification model generation. I converted Response time column to a new true/False column by adding a condition like if ResponseTime > 200, true otherwise false. And deleted original ResponseTime column. So now I have "Memory", "CPU" and "True/False" column and I am running classification algorithms on it. The coefficients generated for Memory and CPU are turning out to be 1 and 0 with DecisionTree for example with kappa=1. For Random Forest, Memory is 0.2 and CPU is 0.7 with Kappa=1